# Adjusting Subclassed UITableViewCell UILabel Frame

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a subclass UITableViewCell.  In storyboard I added some labels and buttons and created respective outlets, and I set and tweaked their respective frames using the size inspector.  The layout looks good for a iPhone 6.  On an iPhone 5 things are off screen on the right.  In the layoutSubviews method of the UITableView subclass I attempt to adjust the frame of my labels and buttons.  When the tableview first appears the buttons and labels are in the positions specified for their respective frames in Storyboard and not in the frame/position I set in layoutSubviews.  A moment later they appear in the positions set in layoutSubviews.  Sometimes however, I see it revert to the old storyboard set position.

Any ideas what might be happening?  I want to set the labels and button frames explicitly and have them stay where I put them.  I don't want to use constraints as they are really painful to use in Storyboard, and frequently don't behave well or with good granularity.

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with cell reuse flow? Instead of subclassing `UITableView` to override `layoutSubviews()`, why don't you try adjusting the frame prior to cell reuse? (`tableView(_:cellforRowAtIndexPath:)`).

Comment: Don't adjust frames.  Set constraints and autolayout will do the rest

Comment: How am I to have a custom cell with buttons and labels with specific behavior if I don't subclass it?  I'm not subclassing merely to override layoutSubviews.  I have a table view that has multiple custom cells.

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't want to use constraints.  When I try to use them I get poor results.  For example I have a button with a clock image and a text label showing minutes to its right.  I want very perfect spacing between them.  If the label is showing single digit number versus double digit the spacing is not tight using constraints where as with frames it is.  An aside I'm bothered that story board doesn't show what you see is what you get spacing when placing things.  It is extremely frustrating to have to continually guess and compile.  One would think Apple could do better.

Comment: Because by default, storyboard is based on Autolayout, not springs/struts/frames.  You can go to the properties of your storyboard and uncheck "use autolayout".  Anything you can do with frames you can do with autolayout.  In your clock example, you could fix the position and size of the label using constraints and get exactly the same result as you would by setting a frame since that is in effect what you are doing

Comment: Paul that will be project wide, right?  I have used constraints on one other screen and it was tortuous.   I don't really want to undo that work.   And I mentioned already that I used constraints on this present screen and wasn't able to achieve the right spacing.  If I have a single digit then there is more space between the button and the digit than I want.  Is there no way to use frames on one screen and auto layout on another?  I guess I shot myself in the foot by trying to use frames at all.  Why does apple even have the setting if autolayout is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use constraints, please remove use auto lay out and use size class.

[image]

Comment: that will be project wide, right?  I have used constraints on one other screen and it was tortuous.  And I mentioned already to Paulw11 that I used constraints here on this present screen, and wasn't able to achieve the right spacing.  If I have a single digit then there is more space between the button and the digit than I want.  So is there no way to use autolayout on one screen and not on another?  If it is indeed project wide, then If I don't use autolayout then I'm throwing away work on another screen and if I do use it I'm throwing away the work I did for this current screen.

Comment: It isn't a good solution if I have to disable auto layout everywhere else.